# A couple issues with magic links

Tags: bug, comments, magic-links

I noticed that some magic links in comment section have weird unfolding. In particular:

1. `[tour]` can be used with any case for any letter. Result links [will keep these cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/975094). Probably because of this we have an [issue with localization](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3132/176217). I think we should leave only two versions in results: `Tour` and `tour` as it done for `[edit]` [magic link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/975097).
2. `[about]` has same issue as for `[tour]` (see above). But also using `[about]` (all small letters) produces link with text: `tour`, not `about`.